# Add message to context.result

Tags: c#, data-annotations, bad-request

I'm creating a DataAnnotation that if not successful will return a BadRequest.

```
context.Result = new BadRequestResult();
```

That works fine.

I want to include a message along with this, but BadRequestResult doesn't appear to take any message params?

Is there a way to do this...include a message to say e.g. "reference number not supplied"

Thanks

Comment: There's an overloaded constructor that takes a message, like [`BadRequestResult(HttpRequestMessage)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.results.badrequestresult(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.Results.BadRequestResult.#ctor(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage))

Answer (score 13):

This appears to work:

```
context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Reference number not supplied.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ApiController.BadRequest("Reference number not supplied")` to pass a message along with the result. Here's the documentation in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.badrequest(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.ApiController.BadRequest%28System.String%29).